# SVG disappears on router navigation

Tags: css, angular, svg

I have an angular component that contains an SVG.
This component is used in many pages and when I first load the site, it shows correctly.

But if I navigate to another page using a `navigateByUrl()`, the SVG shows for about half a second and then disappears.

Using the chrome Dev-Tools, it still shows that the SVG is there, but it just doesn't show.

This would be my SVG:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 414 437" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M-130.749 388.437C140.914 195.366 389.638 804.747 531.425 -171.167L-52.4707 -155.859C-80.307 114.253 -66.7438 29.9665 -66.7438 153.392C-66.7438 256.476 -358.847 550.546 -130.749 388.437Z"
              fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="452.542" y1="-125.851" x2="340.592" y2="212.53"
                            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#17BEB7"/>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#16AAA4"/>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Is there any way you can make it reappear by fiddling with the `svg` styles in the web inspector? For example, does setting `z-index: 9999` make it reappear?

Comment: I remember having a similar issue like this before and it was related to Chrome. Can you try Firefox and/or Edge/Safari to see if it's the same?

Comment: @AndyHoffman No it does not make it reappear

Comment: Can you link to the page so I can test?

Comment: @AliF50 Just tried Firefox -> Same problem.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Sadly not, its local development. Running with `serve`